# I made a simple program in C which calculates the factorial of a number

Tags: c

I made a simple program in C which calculates the factorial of a number, but at the end I want to run the program (again).  Instead of seeing "press any key to continue", I want it to show "press any key to find factorial of a number again".

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int facto, i, m ;
    m=1 ;
    printf("Ener a Value : ");
    scanf("%d", &facto) ;
    for( i=facto-1 ; i>m ; i-- )  
        facto *= i ; 
    printf("My Reg num:SP-16/BBS/033\nFactorial of the number : =%d\n", facto );
    system ("pause") ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> "press any key to continue"

This line comes from your `system(pause)`. If you want to:

1.. find another factorial

2.. print another msg

you should use a loop and a printf, like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int facto, i, m ;
  m=1 ;
  printf("Ener a Value : ");
  while( 0 < scanf("%d", &facto) && facto > 0){
    for( i=facto-1 ; i>m ; i-- )  
      facto *= i ; 
    printf("My Reg num:SP-16/BBS/033\nFactorial of the number : =%d\n",facto); 
  printf("press any key to find factorial of a number again : ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you terminate the program shown?  Is an interrupt or equivalent the only meaningful way?  The code should at least test the return value from `scanf()` so that it doesn't go into an infinite loop if the user types `a` or indicates EOF.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried to keep the program as similar to the OP's as possible. That's why I didn't check the scanf return value, and just explained at the end one option to terminate the loop. As long as the user inputs the "right" data, this should work just fine

Comment: I stand by my initial question: how do you terminate this program? At one level, it is good to keep to the original code, but at another, you're changing things so that it will loop indefinitely on error, whereas the original would not.  The onus is on you to ensure that such misbehaviours do not cause problems like an infinite loop.  So, you have to fix the code to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @Jonathan `^C` terminates it

Comment: @IngoBürk: Yes, but it isn't exactly elegant, is it.  It's quite possible the a key such as `^\\` also terminates it, with a core dump — that isn't elegant either.  And the program should not misbehave on erroneous input or on reading EOF, either.  And Markdown doesn't like the notation I'm trying to use very much, either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me point out that your question is still very unclear. If you meant that you want to run the program continuously as long as the user wants to, then I suggest putting the factorial finding code inside a do-while loop. The while condition will be based on a 'choice' variable. Only when the 'choice' variable receives an input of 'n' (Because the program has to end at some point), will the code cease to rerun.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int facto, i, m ;
char choice='y';

do{
  printf("Ener a Value : ");
  scanf("%d", &facto);
  m=1 ;
  for( i=facto-1 ; i>m ; i-- )  
    facto *= i ; 

  printf("My Reg num:SP-16/BBS/033\nFactorial of the number : =%d\n",facto );
  printf("Press any key to find factorial of a number again");
  scanf("%c", &choice);
  } while(choice!='n');

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &choice);` doesn't wait for "Press any key".

Comment: Note that you need to use `scanf(" %c", &choice)` to skip over the newline left behind by reading the number.  You also need to worry about what happens if the user indicates EOF — it looks like your program would be noisy and would take a long time to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very **simple and clear**. I'm not doing anything to adjust that.

However, if you want to **rerun the whole program** again and again until some point, you should always consider using a **loop with a specific end condition**.

Try this (press **enter** to end the program, **anything else** will repeat it)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int facto, i, m ;
    m=1 ;
    do {
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        printf("Ener a Value : ");
        scanf("%d", &facto) ;
        getchar();
        for( i=facto-1 ; i>m ; i-- )  
        facto *= i ; 
        printf("My Reg num:SP-16/BBS/033\nFactorial of the number : =%d\n", facto );
        printf("press any key to find factorial of a number again (Enter to end): ");
    }
    while ( getchar()!='\n');
}
```